ENOTFOUND: Failed to deploy app package to App Servce
I am trying to deploy my Spring Boot app on Azure App Service using GitHub Actions. When, running the deploy action of the workflow, I get an error-

My application is being deployed on Azure App Service-

Note: The build is successful. Error occurs during deploy phase.

Please share your GitHub repository link if possible.

Sorry, but I will not be able to share the GitHub repository.

My deployment consists of a Spring Boot Application deployed using Azure App Service and MS-SQL Server SQL Database.
Also, the build is successful!

Are you using free trial?

Yes. Here is the github link: https://github.com/singhayush20/assessment-portal

It could be due to limitations with free account. Upgrade to Paid Subscription and try again.

It could be due to the limitations of the Free trail account. Upgrade to paid Subscription.

Scale up the resources in the existing plan of web app or opt for Basic or Premium Plan.


I have created an App Service with Premium Plan and Java17 as runtime stack.

Configured deployment with GitHub during app creation.



I could deploy your project to Azure App Service:


GitHub Workflow:
name: Build and deploy JAR app to Azure Web App - <appname>

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Java version
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: '17'

      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn clean install

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: java-app
          path: '${{ github.workspace }}/target/*.jar'

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: java-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: '<appname>'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_6566EE7040FF419BB86684092443B57C }}
          package: '*.jar'

Portal:


Thank You for this information. I will do what is necessary.
